# Which earthbound has merged with the land in Transylvania?

Tags: world-of-darkness, demon-the-fallen

I know it is in one of the Demon books or in the End of Time books (or hinted in in Masquerade), but I know that there is a demon earthbound who has merged with quite a large patch of land in Transylvania.

Which demon/earthbound is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [Kupala](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Kupala). Also called "[Root of All](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Epistatia)," to make this answer long enough to post.